# The exact number of divisor (n) of a number is given, how to determine the smallest number which has n divisors?

Tags: c++, uri

Problem Description:
Link: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/2869
Description: 1 is a divisor of 6. In addition to 1, it has 3 more divisors of 6: 2, 3 and 6. In total, 6 has 4 divisors, and it is the smallest number that has 4 divisors. Talking about divisor, given a number n, what is the smallest number that has n divisors?

I tried two codes of almost same pattern which results Time Limit Exceeded. The problem gives a hint to solve in MOD 100000007 (Bigmod), But I can't find way to solve in BigMod formula.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int divisors(int);

int main() 
{
    int input = 0,tc;
    cin>>tc;
    while(tc--){
        cin>>input;
        cout<<divisors(input)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
int divisors(int input)
{
    int base = 1;
    int divisorNum = 0;
    int num = 0;
    while(divisorNum != input)
    {
        num = 0;
        for(int i = 1;i <= base; i++)
        {
            if(base%i==0)
            {
                num++;
            }
        }
        divisorNum = num;
        base++;
    }
    base-=1;
    return base;
}
```

I know this system is a lot of time consuming for larger numbers. But I don't know the system of shortening the time. The exact problem can be seen in this url: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/2869

Comment: Since n can be atmost 100, you can precompute a list L such that L[i] is the smallest number with i divisors where i = [1, 100].

Comment: just small hint, you can exclude 1 and base from the for loop and start with divisorNum = 2 with special case for input == 1

Comment: Another idea for optimization: Any number > 1 has at least two divisors (1 and itself). And the second largest divisor is always less or equal to half the number, so you don't need to check all the numbers, just half of them.

Answer (score 1):

First think about how you count the divisors of a positive integer. Take `12` as an example.

You can simply enumerate from 1 to 12 and check whether the enumerated number divides 12: `1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12`. Or you can do prime factorization: `12 = 2^2 * 3^1`. If a divisor is written in the form `2^m * 3^n`, then `m` has three possibilities `0, 1, 2` and `n` has two possibilities `0, 1`, therefore, there are `3 * 2 = 6` divisors.

Then how do you create a minimum number with, for example, `24` divisors? You first do prime factorization on `24`: `24 = 3 * 2 * 2 * 2`. Then the number you are looking for is `2^(3-1)*3^(2-1)*5^(2-1)*7^(2-1)`. So essentially you do prime factorization on `n` to get `k` terms and sort them in descending order (`a_1`, `a_2`, ..., `a_k`). The number you want would be `p_1 ^ (a_1 - 1) * p_2 ^ (a_2 - 1) * ... * p_k ^ (a_k - 1)`, where `p_i` is the `i`th prime number (i.e `p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3, p_3 = 5, p_4 = 7...`). Although it is not strictly proven, but it is "intuitively correct" :) (Quoted from my friend who does applied math). Strictly proving it would require some rigorous math, which is beyond my capabilities (as for now), and not quite appropriate for StackOverflow.

(Note `x ^ y` means "x to the power of y", not `x xor y`.)